# flushed and removed iptables rules, but CSF restores them

Tags: firewall, iptables, csf

Intending to clear my iptables rules (i have like a thousand rules which block many customer IPs, and I can't find which is doing it), I removed all csf.deny entries, then :

- service iptables stop
- csf --disable
- rm /etc/sysconfig/iptables
- iptables --flush
- service iptables status (shows empty rules)
- csf --enable

Now all the rules are restored and added to iptables! This is driving me nuts as I can't stop it. Box is CentOS 5.5 on a VPS, server1.etebaran.com, running CPanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, seems like CSF gets a huge list of rules from SPAMHAUS and drops them all, and also from DSHIELD, thus i could not remove them (there is an option to disable these in csf.conf),

Also the default policy somehow has been change to DROP all, so using this I made it accept all :

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT # iptables way
csf -a 0.0.0.0/0 # csf way
```

And now everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` an IP which you belevie it is blocked in `/etc/csf/`

```
grep IP /etc/csf/* -irl
```

Comment: whats the use? Almost no-one except for myself (with an allow entry in csf.allow) can access the server. i have no specific IP but there are plenty of ranged rules that i think cover almost any ip.